# Add "showing posts x to x of y" in custom post type paginated loop

Tags: loop, count

Is there a way that I can add "Showing posts x to x of y" into a paginated custom post type loop? So for example if I have 100 posts I'm showing 10 posts per page, on /page/3 it would show "Showing posts 21 - 30 of 100".

Answer (score 2):

All query objects have a few built in vars that can help you display this.

Assuming your custom query object is `$query`:

- The total number of posts across all pages is `$query->found_posts`
- The total number of posts for the current page is
  `$query->post_count`
- The current page number is
  `$query->query_vars['paged']`
- The number of posts per page is
  `$query->query_vars['posts_per_page']`

With that in mind, we can do something like this:

```
$pagenum = $query->query_vars['paged'] < 1 ? 1 : $query->query_vars['paged'];
$first = ( ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] ) + 1;
$last = $first + $query->post_count - 1;
echo "Showing posts $first - $last of $query->found_posts";
```

**EDIT** - If you want to use the above with the **main query**, change all instances of `$query` to `$wp_query`